# How to scan AltBeacons of specific UUID in swift?

Tags: swift

In my app, i need to scan both iBeacons and AltBeacons. I'm able to scan iBeacon of specific UUID using coreLocation but not able to scan AltBeacon of specific UUID. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you....